# What is the correct way to propagate errors?

Tags: error-handling, rust

I'm trying to learn Rust, but I am faced with a difficulty when I implement the `fmt::Display` trait for one of my types. I want to do something like this:

```
fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
    write!(f, "(");
    some_helper_function(self.t1, self.ctx, f);
    write!(f, " ");
    some_helper_function(self.t2, self.ctx, f);
    write!(f, ")")
}
```

All of these functions return `fmt::Result`, but this will be ignored. What is correct way for propagating the error result upward?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For every function call you check if the return is an `Err` object or not. If it's an `Err` object you return from the function, if not you continue.
There's a convenient macro in the standard library, called [try!](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/macro.try!.html) which does exactly this.

So your code would become something like this:

```
fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
    try!(write!(f, "("));
    try!(some_helper_function(self.t1, self.ctx, f));
    try!(write!(f, " "));
    try!(some_helper_function(self.t2, self.ctx, f));
    try!(write!(f, ")"))
}
```

Comment: *an Err object* — being pedantic, `Err` is a *variant* of the `Result` enum.

Comment: `try!` is a [no longer recommended](https://rustbyexample.com/hello/print/print_display/testcase_list.html) way of doing it. use `?` instead: i.e. `write!(f, "(")?;`

Answer (score 0):

[Andrea P's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32412625/155423) is spot on for how to fix this. I wanted to add on to this part though:

> All of these functions return `fmt::Result`, but this will be ignored.

Note that the compiler tries really hard to help you here:

```
fn important() -> Result<u8, ()> {
    Err(())
}

fn main() {
    important();
}
```

Will produce this warning by default:

```
warning: unused result which must be used, #[warn(unused_must_use)] on by default
     important();
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

You can even make it so that all warnings become errors by adding this to your crate:

```
#![deny(unused_must_use)]
```